# how to give xml file source in app.config and write/read those xml files form winform?

Tags: asp.net, winforms, app-config, csharpcodeprovider

```
DataSet ds = CreateDynamicDataSet();
ds.WriteXml(@"E:\AppScienti\AppScienti-POSLite\POSLite-Dev\XML\POSLite.xml");

private DataSet CreateDynamicDataSet()
{

    DataSet ds = new DataSet("DS");
    //ds.Namespace = "StdNamespace";
    dtOutletMapping.TableName = "Tables[2]";
    ds.Tables.Add(dtOutletMapping);
    dtxmlEmployee.TableName = "Tables[0]";
    ds.Tables.Add(dtxmlEmployee);
    dtxmlOrg.TableName = "Tables[1]";
    ds.Tables.Add(dtxmlOrg);

    return ds;
}
```

In above code I have path directly in winform and its working fine, now I want to keep path in `app.config` and use a path to write a dataset into file
any possible solution please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you have added reference to `System.Configuration`. (Right click on project and select "Add Refrence" and find it in ".Net" tab).

Modify the app.config file as shown below: Under `appSettings`, add your file name as shown below.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="xmlFile" value="c:\\users\\test.xml" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Now in the code add the namespace

```
using System.Configuration;
```

And when you want read the file name, do it as shown below

```
string filename = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("xmlFile");

DataSet ds = CreateDynamicDataSet();
ds.WriteXml(filename);
```